"Освещался светом" - плеоназм или нет?

Комната была освещена мягким зеленоватым светом...

Плеоназм или нет? Если да, каким образом выразить мысль цитируемого отрывка?

Это тавтология, а не плеоназм.

И плеоназм и тавтология

Любая тавтология является плеоназмом, но не всякий плеоназм является тавтологией

Есть тавтологии не являющиеся плеоназмом.


Если уж обсуждать освещен светом, то говорить нужно о тавтологии, то есть о повторе однокоренных слов.

По словарю не тавтология, да, но вот интересный момент: наш слух в любом случае привлекает повтор сходных или одинаковых слов. Художественный повтор нравится, а языковой не очень. А как же быть?
И вот тогда мы используем распространенные определения, разделяющие однокоренные слова. Опять же в слове освещен корень СВЕЩ, а не СВЕТ.

Вот статья:

Что такое плеоназм и тавтология и в чём между ними разница
Тавтология и плеоназмы — фигуры речи, при которых в словосочетаниях или предложениях есть повторы. Но в одном случае повторяются одинаковые или однокоренные слова, а в другом — близкие по смыслу, не добавляющие никакого значения.
Плеоназм — фигура речи, при которой одно слово дублирует какой-то элемент смысла из другого. То есть в одном фрагменте текста используются слова, которые повторяют какой-то смысл и не добавляют ничего нового. В плеоназме не повторяются слова, а добавляются лишние.
Например: первый дебют (дебют может быть только первым, любое последующее выступление — не дебют), вернуться назад (вернуться можно только назад, поэтому слово «назад» не добавляет никакого смысла), главный приоритет, ценное сокровище и т.д.
Тавтология — разновидность плеоназма, при которой в предложении или словосочетании повторяются схожие по звучанию/значению или однокоренные слова. Иначе говоря, тавтология — неоправданный повтор однокоренных слов.

А это Пушкин А.С.
Вся комната янтарным блеском
Озарена. Веселым треском
Трещит затопленная печь.



Трещит треском — это художественная тавтология, да?


Комната была озарена мягким зеленоватым светом

См. примеры:
Долина была озарена прохладно-зеленоватым светом, отражавшимся от центральной ледяной вершины.  (Терри Пратчетт. Последний герой. Сказание о плоском мире.)
Вся эта, прямо скажем, убогая обстановка была озарена таким родниковым зеленоватым – от берёз за окном – светом, такой покой лился в огромное, как и все в школьном здании, не занавешенное окно, что Сташек притих и сидел на стуле очень прямо, очень смирно и даже задумчиво. (Дина Рубина. Яша, ты этого хотел?)
Комната озарена зеленоватым светом: свет льется из аквариума , где среди освещенных электрической лампочкой водорослей плавают красноперые рыбешки. (Николай Антонов. Большой мир Нюры маленькой.)

Заря зеленого цвета? И солнце тоже. Находка для фантастов)

"Озарить" означает то же самое, что и "осветить", т. е. залить светом, ситуация аналогична цитируемой

Зато избавляет от тавтологии. Плеоназма тут не должно быть - можно озарить зеленым светом или красным, уже типа нет смысловой избыточности. Но если уж совсем её избегать, то надо озарять мягкой зеленью. Но это уже бред конечно.

Комната была залита мягким зеленым светом.

Пламя захлебнулось стеарином, постреляло во все стороны трескучими звездочками и заострилось стрелкой.  Комната наполнилась мягким светом.  Во льду оконного стекла на уровне свечи стал протаивать черный глазок.
[Б. Л. Пастернак. Доктор Живаго (1945-1955)]

Все таки "комната наполнилась" и "комната была наполнена" это две разные вещи. С другой стороны в общем контексте все кошки серы. Все фразы сгодятся, более-менее выражающие смысл.

Какая нафиг литература, мы на форуме РЯ при чем тут грёбаная литература. А вам надо логику подтянуть, тогда может не будете пенять на литературу в качестве доказательства. Короче, я с вами же не общаюсь, а то на матюги только тянет.

@user190920, извините за вмешательство в Ваш ответ: добавил в него несколько примеров из литературы, чтобы прекратить наскоки на Ваш ответ со стороны некой особы. Если сочтёте эти примеры лишними, уберите их.

Спасибо, лишним не будет, но проще со стеной дискутировать, больше пользы.

Участник Слава очень любит объединяться против некой особы. Ищет себе товарищей. Оценочная лексика уже в ходу: особа, наскоки, стена. Культура общения на форуме на высоте. Дружелюбная такая атмосфера. А это фантастика, там действительно много зелени, как я и говорила https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словосочетанием/мягкий+зелёный+свет Неожиданно комната осветилась зеленоватым светом, и я заметил каких-то странных человечков.

В реальных же текстах зеленоватый свет связан со световыми эффектами отражения и преломления света и обычно несет дополнительную художественную нагрузку.   Поэтому во всех случаях присутствует пояснение (зеленый цвет от берез, от водорослей).

Думаю, что нет в вашем предложении ни тавтологии, ни плеоназма.
• Подтверждение первое (толковый словарь)
осветить
1.0. Излучая свет, зажёгшись, сделать кого-что-либо видным, наполнить что-либо светом...
Осветить кого-что-либо каким-либо (например, бледным, неверным, ярким, слепящим...) светом (какими-либо лучами...)...
• Подтверждение второе (примеры)
Комната была освещена мертвенно-бледным светом, исходящим, как я узнал впоследствии, от химического горна (Артур Конан Дойл).
...от этого и сама комната была освещена каким-то удивительно ярким, радужным светом (Ганс Христиан Андерсен).
Комната была освещена льющимся откуда-то сверху красным светом... (Сергей Бовтунов).
...помещение было освещено призрачным слабым светом (Антон Леонтьев).
Комната была освещена приятным для глаз обволакивающим светом, который струился с потолка... (Кирилл Салтыков).
Чердак был освещен слабым, колеблющимся светом... ("Дальний Восток", 1982).
